# Redis Performance Issue with LRANGE on a big list

Tags: python, redis

I have a huge list of items (about 10,000 items) in mylist and I need to retrieve the list almost every second in 20+ processes.

LRANGE mylist 0 -1 takes too long. HKEYS should be any better? Any alternatives? Thanks much!!!

```
127.0.0.1:6379> slowlog get 10
1) 1) (integer) 3
   2) (integer) 1637075048
   3) (integer) 21702
   4) 1) "LRANGE"
      2) "mylist"
      3) "0"
      4) "-1"
   5) "[::1]:42268"
   6) ""
2) 1) (integer) 2
   2) (integer) 1637074986
   3) (integer) 52563
   4) 1) "LRANGE"
      2) "mylist"
      3) "0"
      4) "-1"
   5) "[::1]:42268"
   6) ""
3) 1) (integer) 1
   2) (integer) 1637074923
   3) (integer) 20673
   4) 1) "LRANGE"
      2) "mylist"
      3) "0"
      4) "-1"
   5) "[::1]:42266"
   6) ""
4) 1) (integer) 0
   2) (integer) 1637074385
   3) (integer) 16242
   4) 1) "LRANGE"
      2) "mylist"
      3) "0"
      4) "-1"
   5) "[::1]:42266"
   6) ""
127.0.0.1:6379> exit
```

Comment: yes because you are fetching the "whole" list -> taken into memory -> move in network. why do you need to get whole list ? What is your use case ?

Comment: Well, we have a huge dataset like stock with 10M hashes .. and trying to store key names for each product in a separate list and product names (about 10k) in another list..

Comment: We need to iterate through the whole 10k products and 1000 hashes (more like rows) for product..